# TSA-PreCheck not showing on Delta boarding pass

Tags: usa, air-travel, delta-air-lines, tsa-precheck, nexus

I received TSA precheck via NEXUS (or at least I presume I did since it's included with NEXUS) over a month and a half ago, and added the KTN (Known Traveler Number) to my Delta Skymiles profile. I booked my Delta flight after this was added. Today I checked in 24 hours before my flight but could not see TSA PRE on my boarding pass. I called customer support and verified the name, number and other details and it seems to be matching.

The only difference I see is that my first, middle and last name (say X, Y, Z) is Given Names: X Y, and Surname: Z on my NEXUS card whereas on my Delta profile 
it is First Name: X, Middle name: Y, and Last Name: Z

Is this enough to throw off the TSA database into not issuing me a pre-check boarding pass?

I cannot change any information 72 hours before flight so I will try at the check-in counter again, but has anyone faced this issue and resolved it?

Comment: Once in a blue moon, I'll have a flight where I don't get precheck, I'll go 12 rounds with the airline and TSA trying to fix it, they'll all deny any problem but not be able to fix it, and then it will work again on the next flight with the exact same name and information. It usually seems to happen on flights that could plausibly be designated "higher risk" (e.g. a short notice one-way booking to New York), which makes me suspect it's intentional, but nobody will ever confirm that.

Comment: Ok, thanks your answer shed some light on it. I'll try at the counter, or else just sweat it out in the regular lanes!

Comment: In case you were not aware, Precheck is not guaranteed, even if all your information is in order. There will still be random occasions where they send you to screening.

Comment: Yes I was aware of that. This was my first time using Tsa precheck so I was hoping everything will go smoothly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to [ask the TSA to check into it](https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2016/04/05/asktsa-travel-tips-over-140-characters-help-i-didnt-get-tsa-precheck-my-boarding-pass):

> Follow @AskTSA on Twitter and direct message the following:
>
> Full name
>
> Known Traveler Number (KTN)
>
> Airline
>
> Confirmation Number
>
> A member of our team will contact you and help you figure out why you’re not receiving TSA Pre✓®. It's important that you're enrolled in TSA Pre✓®, Global Entry, Nexus or Sentry.
>
> If you’re not a Twitter user, or would rather speak to somebody on the phone, you can reach out to our TSA Contact Center [866-289-9673].

I haven't always had success with this (they've claimed the name needs to be adjusted when it's the same name that always works), but they should check on it and get back to you.